# Is it possible to remove this floating wooden pallet in House Flipper?

Tags: house-flipper

In House Flipper for PC (on Steam, with Garden Flipper DLC), I can't quite figure out how to remove this piece of trash that's floating alongside the telephone lines. Even when jumping on top of the big scaffold I can't get high enough to actually reach the wooden pallet that's up there. (Not sure how it got up there; probably the questionable physics engine in this game.)

Is there a trick to reaching this trash? It's still within the boundaries of the plot that I'm renovating, so it should be technically reachable if I could get high enough.

[image: Floating pallet]